# grep with regex not working by non-root user

Tags: grep, ubuntu-20.04

My command is `./test`. I want to get the pid of process.

my code:

```bash
Distro: Ubuntu 20.04(grep v3.4)

# run command by test user
test@host:~$ ps -ef | grep tes[t]
test .....    ./test
test .....    grep --color=auto test
       grep with regex not working.

# run command by root user
root@host:~# ps -ef | grep tes[t]
root .....    ./test
    It's Working.
```

I found that run `ps -ef | grep tes[t]` by test user(**other non-root user also has the same problem**), grep with regex not working.
I found that root user is alway working.

`ps -ef | grep tes[t]`

| Distro | It's working? |
| --- | --- |
| Ubuntu 20.04 non-root user | ❎ |
| Ubuntu 20.04 root user | ✅ |
| Ubuntu 22.04 non-root user | ✅ |
| Ubuntu 22.04 root user | ✅ |

Why the command is not working on Ubuntu 20.04 with non-root user?

PS: I know `ps -ef | grep "tes[t]"` (regex string has been quoted) is alwasy working.

Comment: `not working` is the worst possible problem description as it tells us nothing about the problem and so makes it almost impossible for us to help you diagnose and fix it. You also haven't shown us the output of `ps -ef` for each user so we don't even know if the grep regexp you're showing us should match anything or not.

Comment: The first thing anyone (or any tool such as http://shellcheck.net) would point out is that you aren't quoting the grep argument so you should fix that to be `ps -ef | grep 'tes[t]'` but then you say `I know ps -ef | grep "tes[t]" (regex string has been quoted) is alwasy working` so ... it sounds like you already know the fix so it's really unclear what question you're asking.

Comment: This should be asked in ubuntu stack exchange, not S.O.

Comment: @TaoHuang don't try to add information in comments where it can;t be formatted and could be missed, [edit] your question to contain all information. Also, a table of `It's working?` checkmarks still doesn't tell us in what way anything is not "working" nor does it show us the output of `ps -ef` when it is/isn't "working".